# Counting objects from AWS and warning if too many

Tags: bash, aws, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create bash script. When I run the AWS command I get a "Total Objects" on the bottom of the results. I want to trigger a warning if its greater than 50 objects.

```
aws s3 ls test.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/ --human-readable --summarize
value=$( grep -ic "Total Objects")
if [ $value -gt 50 ]
then 
  echo "Warning"
fi
```

Here is the updated code:

```
value=$(aws s3 ls test.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/  --human-readable --summarize | grep -ic "Total Objects")
if [ $value -gt 10 ];
then
    echo "Warning"
fi
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: show the bottom output of `aws` command

Comment: Here is the output: Total Objects: 53
   Total Size: 7.0 MiB

Answer (score 2):

Incorporate `aws` and `grep` inside the command substitution, `$()`:

```
value=$(aws s3 ls test.domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/ --human-readable --summarize | grep -ic "Total Objects")
```

Currently you are getting output from `aws` to STDOUT and `grep` has no file to operate on.

Comment: Thank you.. It's getting better. I'm not getting an error, but I'm not seeing the echo "Warning". I have verified the value and the results are still greater than 50.

Comment: @ITDevon Whats th output of `echo $value`?

Comment: It does not display any echo's. it just returns back to the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ value=$(echo 'Total Objects: 53 Total Size: 7.0 MiB '|grep -oP '(?<=Total Objects: )\d+')
$ echo $value
53
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route, I used this code to accomplish what I wanted to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(aws s3 ls bucket/dir1/dir2/ -- recursive --human-readable --summarize | grep .file type | wc -l)
if [ $value -gt 1000 ];
then
      echo "$value Warning"
      exit 2
fi
```

Thank you Everyone for the help

Devon